# Perform normality test (Lilliefors) simultaneously on all variables (including subsetted) in R

Tags: r, statistics, bioinformatics, biometrics

I've installed the nortest package for the Lilliefors test, but as `lillie.test(x)` only allows me to test for one variable at a time, I will have to manually do 100s of this, as my dataset has many subgroups and variables.

Is there a generic code I can apply on R to run this test simultaneously on all individual variables/subgroups (e.g. `maindata$variable1, subset1$variable1, subset2$variable1, subset2$variable2, subset3$variable1, subset3$variable2`, etc) and generate a list?

Thanks in advance :)

---

EDIT - sample dataset

```
      EyeColour      HairColour     Weight       Height    Gender
1          Brown        Black          1.4         0.2      M
2          Brown        Blond          1.4         0.2      F
3          Blue         Black          1.3         0.2      M
4          Brown        Blond          1.5         0.2      F
5          Blue         Black          1.4         0.2      M
6          Blue         Blond          1.7         0.4      F
900        ...          ...             ...          ...    ...
```

Essentially, if I wanted to assess normality via Lilliefors for height for BrownEyes+BlackHair, BlueEyes+BlackHair, and then also BrownEyes+BlackHair+Male, BrownEyes+BlackHair+Female, etc...

I can do this manually, but I have about 40 numeric variables and wonder if there's an easier way to do than manually for each one.

What I'm intending to generate would be automated repeats of `lillie.test(x)` for all these variable combinations, and get something like this:

```
 HEIGHT                          P-VALUE
BlueEyes+BlackHair              0.11212
BlueEyes+BlackHair              0.40001
BrownEyes+BlackHair+Male         0.532
BrownEyes+BlackHair+Female       0.7674
```

Comment: Are these subsets additional datasets? Or groups within your main dataset?

Comment: groups within the main dataset!

Comment: Please post a data example, giving the grouping variables (factors?) and what variables to test. A small example please, with a structure similar to your real use case.

Comment: I have found a halfway solution!

Comment: My halfway solution - `lapply(maindataset[,c("height", "weight")], function(x) lillie.test(x))`, but it means having to create and repeat this for every subset within my main dataset, e.g. `blueeyes<-subset(maindataset, blueeyes==1)` and then `blueeyesbrownhair<-subset(blueeyes, brownhair==1), and then running `lapply` to each one.

Comment: Instead of `lapply`, try `group_by()` and `mutate()` in the `dplyr` package

Comment: Thanks Joris! Do you have a link to an example for using group_by() and mutate()? I found a few Googling around, but I can't tease out the steps myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to respond when you provide reproducible data. It is not hard to make some up:

```
set.seed(42)
EyeColour <- sample(c("Blue", "Brown", "Green"), 500, replace=TRUE)
HairColour <- sample(c("Black", "Blond", "Red"), 500, replace=TRUE)
Weight <- rnorm(500, 1.5, .15)
Height <- rnorm(500, .3, .05)
Gender <- sample(c("F", "M"), 500, replace=TRUE)
dfm <- data.frame(EyeColour, HairColour, Weight, Height, Gender)
```

Now we just use `split` and `lapply`:

```
dfm.split <-split(dfm, dfm[, c("EyeColour", "HairColour", "Gender")])
library(nortest)
wgt.norm <- lapply(dfm.split, function(x) lillie.test(x$Weight))
hgt.norm <- lapply(dfm.split, function(x) lillie.test(x$Height))
```

The results are returned as lists for all of the combinations. Things are a bit more complicated if some of the groups have fewer than 5 observations (the minimum required for the test):

```
wgt.norm[1]
# $Blue.Black.F
# 
#   Lilliefors (Kolmogorov-Smirnov) normality test
# 
# data:  x$Weight
# D = 0.11064, p-value = 0.4328
hgt.norm[1]
# $Blue.Black.F
# 
#   Lilliefors (Kolmogorov-Smirnov) normality test
# 
# data:  x$Height
# D = 0.11593, p-value = 0.3586
```

You will need to read up on `split`, `lapply`, and how to work with `lists`, but they are designed for addressing the kind of problem you are working on.